# Why tf_agent variables do not change even after training?

Tags: tensorflow, variables, tensorflow2.0, reinforcement-learning, agent

### tf version : 2.3.0

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from tf_agents.agents.reinforce import reinforce_agent
from tf_agents.drivers import dynamic_step_driver
from tf_agents.environments import suite_gym, tf_py_environment
from tf_agents.eval import metric_utils
from tf_agents.metrics import tf_metrics
from tf_agents.networks import actor_distribution_network
from tf_agents.replay_buffers import tf_uniform_replay_buffer
from tf_agents.trajectories import trajectory
from tf_agents.utils import common

tf.compat.v1.enable_v2_behavior()

env_name='CartPole-v0'
num_iterations=1
collect_episodes_per_iteration=2
replay_buffer_capacity=2000

fc_layer_params=(100, )

learning_rate=1e-3
log_interval=5
num_eval_episodes=10
eval_interval=10

env=suite_gym.load(env_name)

env.reset()

time_step=env.reset()

train_py_env=suite_gym.load(env_name)

train_env=tf_py_environment.TFPyEnvironment(train_py_env)
actor_net=actor_distribution_network.ActorDistributionNetwork(train_env.observation_spec(), train_env.action_spec(), fc_layer_params=fc_layer_params)

optimizer=tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
train_step_counter=tf.compat.v2.Variable(0)

tf_agent=reinforce_agent.ReinforceAgent(train_env.time_step_spec(),
train_env.action_spec(),
actor_network=actor_net,
optimizer=optimizer,
normalize_returns=True,
train_step_counter=train_step_counter)

tf_agent.initialize()

eval_policy=tf_agent.policy
collect_policy=tf_agent.collect_policy

replay_buffer=tf_uniform_replay_buffer.TFUniformReplayBuffer(
data_spec=tf_agent.collect_data_spec,
batch_size=train_env.batch_size,
max_length=replay_buffer_capacity
)

tf_agent.train=common.function(tf_agent.train)

def collect_episode(environment, policy, num_episodes):
    episode_counter=0
    environment.reset()

    while episode_counter<num_episodes:
        time_step=environment.current_time_step()
        action_step=policy.action(time_step)
        next_time_step=environment.step(action_step.action)
        traj=trajectory.from_transition(time_step, action_step, next_time_step)
      
        replay_buffer.add_batch(traj)

        if traj.is_boundary():
            episode_counter+=1

collect_episode(train_env, tf_agent.collect_policy, 1)
experience=replay_buffer.gather_all()

for _ in range(num_iterations):
    collect_episode(train_env, tf_agent.collect_policy, collect_episodes_per_iteration)

    from copy import copy

    before=copy(tf_agent.trainable_variables)
    experience=replay_buffer.gather_all()
    train_loss=tf_agent.train(experience)
    replay_buffer.clear()

    after=copy(tf_agent.trainable_variables)
    print('before==after?', before==after)
```

---

https://www.tensorflow.org/agents/tutorials/6_reinforce_tutorial

I was following tutorials of TFAgents, but I found that

```
before=copy(tf_agent.trainable_variables)

tf_agent.train(experience)     

after=copy(tf_agent.trainable_variables)
```

Then 'before' should be different with 'after'.
But (before==after) always represents 'True'.

I am very confusing about this. I thought that gradients might be zero.

However, it it unreasonable  cause the model's loss continues to decrease in a training step.

On reinforce_agent module, gradient tape step was written well..

I can't find what is the problem...
even tf_agent.policy.trainable_variables is the same regardless of a training step..

Comment: Can you edit your question and only include the parts of your code that are absolutely necessary? Otherwise there is little chance of anyone reading your entire question. Read this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks, I changed my code as briefly as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that `tf_agent.trainable_variables` is a tuple of tf.Variables (which are tensors). Copying these Tensors with `copy` doesn't do what you expect and what happens is that the tensors in `before` get updated as the agent trains. To actually see the difference try this code:

```
before = []

for element in tf_agent.trainable_variables:
  before.append(tf.identity(element))

tf_agent.train(experience)

after = []

for element in tf_agent.trainable_variables:
  after.append(tf.identity(element))
print(before == after)
```

Comment: Thank! I found that the agent is actually training!